# Copy the Images referenced in the CSS Files to des folder while using cssmin plugin and bower

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, bower

I want to use Grunt (as a Task Runner) and Bower (as a package manager) newly for My projects, but I have a problem when using [cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin) Grunt plugin to minify css files.

Suppose I have three folder in `bower_component` folder like this:

```
└── components
|    ├── bootstrap
|    │   ├── img
|    │   │   └── glyhs.gif
|    │   └── css
|    │       └── bootstrap.css
|    └── bxslider-4
|    |   ├── css
|    |   │   └── jquery.bxslider.min.css
|    |   └── images
|    |        ├── next.gif
|    |        └── prev.gif
|    |
|    |__another_plugin
|       |__css
|       |   |__all.css
|       |__all_images
|           |__picture.png
|__css
    |_img
    |_all_style.min.css
```

And Now I want to minify all these css files into a `all_style.min.css` file on a directory named `css`.

For that I wrote bellow into `Gruntfile.js` file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        cssmin: {
            options: {
                shorthandCompacting: false,
                roundingPrecision: -1
            },
            target: {
                files: {
                    'css/all_style.min.css': [
                        'bower_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css',
                        'bower_components/bxslider-4/jquery.bxslider.min.css'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

};
```

Css minifying works fine but problem is that references to image in main css files is relative to each plugin folder and after minifying browser can not found them.

I want a way that along with minifying css file ,in addition to copy image referenced in the CSS Files into dest `img` folder ,all previous image url changed to proper one based on new place.

I search for that and readed [how-to-rewrite-urls-of-images-in-vendor-css-files-using-grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254068/how-to-rewrite-urls-of-images-in-vendor-css-files-using-grunt)  and similar question but beacause have not any GruntFile configuration, I could not understand what did they do.

**Update:**

This is my `package.js` content :

```
{
  "name": "gabrabad",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "ahmadbadpey",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: what images? can you be more specific? can you show a part of your code? and full grunt.js file ? are you getting a path error problem ?

Comment: @Raduken, images that are in folder of each plugin and referenced by plugins css files.above is full my grunt.js file.I have not error but after minifying, images of used in compressed version of css files could not found.

Comment: can you provide your package.json? i will do a local test, thanks

Comment: I added package.js file content

Comment: sorry for did not come back to you, I got kinda busy, you still need the help?

Comment: yes I have problem Still.